# How can I pass a List of int lists to a jitclass when some int lists are empty?

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to create a jitclass function with List of int lists in it.

I tried various scenarios (as shown in the below example) but I always have an error saying :
    ValueError: Cannot type empty list

The issue is that I need sometime the int list to be empty, which causes the error

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass,jit,njit,typeof
from numba import boolean, int32, float64,uint8

# spec1 = [
#     ('list_int' ,int32[:]),
#     ('list_float' ,float64[:]),]

# spec1 = [
#     ('list_int' ,typeof([[],[1,2],[1,2,3,4,5,],[]])),
#     ('list_float' ,typeof([[3.2],[],[3.3,6.8,5.],[]]))]

spec1 = [
    ('list_int'   ,typeof(tuple([[],[1,2],[1,2,3,4,5,],[]]))),
    ('list_float' ,typeof(tuple([[3.2],[],[3.3,6.8,5.],[]])))]

@jitclass(spec1)
class example():
    def __init__(self, list_int, list_float):
        self.list_int          = list_int
        self.list_float     = list_float


list_intA = [[],[1,2],[1,2,3,4,5,],[]]
list_floatB = [[3.2],[],[3.3,6.8,5.],[]]

# my_ex = example( list_intA ,
#                  list_floatB )

my_ex = example( tuple([np.array(l, dtype=np.int32) for l in list_intA]) ,
                 tuple([np.array(l, dtype=np.float64) for l in list_floatB]) )

# my_ex = example(np.array([np.array(l, dtype=np.int32) for l in list_intA]),
#                 np.array([np.array(l, dtype=np.int32) for l in list_floatB]))
```

Comment: Problem is that if you don't initialize variables numba cannot infer their type, and it cannot do is job. See here, point 1.7.2, maybe it helps https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand how to initialize variables. the variables of the jitclass are initialized in the __init__ rigth?

Comment: Yes, in the constructor.

Comment: So, that what I did. I'm confused :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with a solution. The type passed to the jitclass wasn't right.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass,jit,njit,typeof, types,typed

spec1 = [
    ('list_int'   , types.List(typeof(np.array([], dtype=np.int32)))),
    ('list_float'   , types.List(typeof(np.array([], dtype=np.float64)))),
        ]


@jitclass(spec1)
class example():
    def __init__(self, list_int, list_float  ):
        self.list_int          = list_int
        self.list_float          = list_float


list_intA = [[],[1,2],[1,2,3,4,5,],[-1]]
list_floatB = [[],[1.,2.],[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,],[-1.]]

my_ex = example( [np.array(l, dtype=np.int32) for l in list_intA],
                 [np.array(l, dtype=np.float64) for l in list_floatB])
```